# Missing index explanation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm checking all the queries that I run and this is what I see as suggested missed index (for example)

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[MBLPosition] ([DeviceKey])
INCLUDE ([PositionKey])
GO
```

Tables DDL look like so(not full)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MBLPosition](
    [PositionKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PositionGKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DeviceKey] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_MBLPosition] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PositionKey] ASC)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MBLPosition]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MBLPosition_MBLDevice_DeviceKey] FOREIGN KEY([DeviceKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MBLDevice] ([DeviceKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MBLPosition] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MBLPosition_MBLDevice_DeviceKey]
GO
```

I thought that all FK's already indexes. No? And what does it mean `INCLUDE ([PositionKey])`
 ?

Comment: FK automatically creating indexes is a common misconception - read about it: [When did SQL Server stop putting indexes on foreign key columns?](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/When-did-SQL-Server-stop-putting-indexes-on-Foreign-Key-columns.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And what does it mean INCLUDE ([PositionKey]) ?

This question is indeed the key to the answer. You can add columns to your index to improve performance:

> An index with included nonkey columns can significantly improve query performance when all columns in the query are included in the index either as key or nonkey columns.

If you run a lot of queries that look like this

```
select PositionKey from MBLPosition where DeviceKey = @key
```

your query wouldn't need to touch the table at all - it will be a quick index lookup.

Comment: Yes, I run queries like select MAX(PositionKey) from MBLPosition GROUP BY DeviceKey.. Now I wonder why production server didn't suggest this index and my dev machine did :)

Comment: @katit Indexing suggestions depend on the data that you have in your tables. What makes sense to index in a 1000000+ row table may not make sense to index in a 120-row table, because a full-table scan might be equally fast.

Answer (score 2):

No, FKeys are not indexes.

INCLUDE clause in CREATE INDEX statement forces to include field(s) into b-tree of index onto leaf level of it - it is very useful for designing covering indexes,

**BUT**

in your case the INCLUDE stmt. is meaningless, because it asks to include the column that is already the only primary key column, which is included into any non-clustered index by default onto the leaf level.

Comment: So, thats a bug in SQL Management Studio? Why did it suggest that?

Comment: No, this is not a bug at all. You may look on it as on a better explaination of index structure. With or without INCLUDE the indexes will be just identical

Answer (score 1):

No: Foreign Key references do not automatically have an index created with them.

`INCLUDE` means that the data will be held in the leaf nodes of the index, but not in the internal index nodes themselves. It's useful because it can eliminate the need for an extra lookup into the clustered index.

- [Designing Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190804.aspx)
- [Index with Included Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No.  Foreign keys are not indexed by default.  It is suggesting that you create an index on the FK column and include the PositionKey column as additional data contained with the FK in the index.  This way a query that uses the index and only needs the FK and the PositionKey need never examine the table, it can get all it needs directly from the index.  You can read more about indexes with included columns at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx